# How to sort related objects based on the timestamp of when we are associating the two objects?

Tags: django, django-models, django-3.1

i'm trying to sort objects based on the time when i associate the two objects.

For example, i have these two models:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    order = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, help_text="The order of albums to be displayed.")


class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    stage_name = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    albums = models.ManyToManyField(Album, blank=True)
```

I have an `Album` model, that have an `order` field to sort the priority of the album when we display it on the API. Now, of course it is working when i sort the albums based on the `order` field:

```
artist = Artist.objects.get(id=76)
album1 = Album.objects.create(title="Untitled Album", order=2)
album2 = Album.objects.create(title="Magical Nights", order=1)
artist.albums.add(album1, album2)
albums = Album.objects.filter(artist=artist).order_by('order')
print(albums)

>> <QuerySet [<Album: Magical Nights>, <Album: Untitled Album>]>
```

But when i have some albums with the same priority, i want to also sort the objects based on the timestamp of when i associate the item. Something like this:

```
artist2 = Artist.objects.get(id=77)
new_album1 = Album.objects.create(title="Sapphire Blue", order=1)
new_album2 = Album.objects.create(title="Now We're Strangers", order=2)
new_album3 = Album.objects.create(title="Fight For You", order=1)
artist2.albums.add(new_album3)
artist2.albums.add(new_album2)
artist2.albums.add(new_album1)

albums = Album.objects.filter(artist=artist2).order_by('order')
print(albums)

>> <QuerySet [<Album: Sapphire Blue>, <Album: Fight For You>, <Album: Now We're Strangers>]>
```

My expected result is that when we filter based on `order` and the timestamp, it will be something like this:

```
>> <QuerySet <Album: Fight For You>, [<Album: Sapphire Blue>, <Album: Now We're Strangers>]>
```

If i only sort based on order, it might not always sort based on the time when i add the album to the artist. Is there a way to do this? I can't seem to find the right keyword to search or method to do this. Thank you so much.

Comment: You can order by multiple fields, so say you want it based on order and release date `.order_by('order', '-release_date')`

Comment: hi @BrianDestura, i'm actually not trying to sort based on the ```release_date```, but based on which album is associated first to the artist.

Comment: A [custom through table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) might be what you want, since you need to store details about the relationship between album and artist. You could also move `order` here

Comment: hi @BrianDestura that's a really good idea. i also forgot that the ManyToManyField has its own through model, i will try to filter using the through model first. thanks so much!